# TinyMCE: Get the name of the page that I'm editing

Tags: jquery, tinymce-4

I've made a custom window that opens from the tool bar in TinyMCE. My question is how can I get the name of the page that I'm editing. I need to pass it to the url value in my popup.

Example is given below:

```
url: 'MyScript.pl?PageName=PageNameNeedsToGoHere',
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'page name'? The url of the page containing the mce editor?

Comment: Well when I go to edit a page I click on the page named EX: index.html and then it opens in the editor I need to pass that name "index" to the popup that I created

Comment: I tried url: "MyScript.pl?PageName=" + url,

Comment: And that returns: http://www.domainName.com/Code/3rd Party/Tiny-MCE/plugins/properties

Answer (score 0):

Got it with placing a variable: "var PageName = "index"; on the page that being edited and placed url: 'PageProperties.pl?PageName=' + PageName, on my new popup.